# How to perform membership provider authetication using the WCF?

Tags: .net, wcf, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication, formsauthentication

I am extending an ASP.NET application to provide web services using WCF.  I have to use WSHttpContextBinding so the application can keep track of the user's session. So far I've been successful in connecting to the site without any authentication, but I would like some security.  Currently, I would like to put the service.svc inside an admin folder that is secured using forms authentication. Currently, if put my service.svc there and try to type the url for my service.svc I get the standard windows authentication dialog.  I've read several posts on this, but it's all pretty confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I could not fully understand you problem with WCF and authentication service, but have you had a look at [WCF authentication service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386582.aspx) which is build over membership provider. 
If you plan to authenticate user using a WCF service, which is running in ASP.net compatibility mode then the method that does authentication should be allowed anonymous access.